# Edit a web page button with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML/CSS and I want to edit the style of a button.
This is the html code:

```html
<div class="sign-in-wrap">
<a href="#" target="_self" class="btn-sign-in">START EXPLORING</a>
</div>
```

and this is the CSS:

```css
.btn-sign-in {
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #10cb6c;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  -o-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  white-space: nowrap
}

.btn-sign-in:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2add82
}
```

What I want to achieve is this style https://codepen.io/Cyris/pen/abpjJrK.

Already tried to apply the CSS code to my `.btn-sign-in` from the link above but is not working at 100%.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: use button element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the button component, not the link

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Please use this
`<button class="btn-sign-in">START EXPLORING</button>`